# Migration from SOAPUI Pro(ReadyAPI) to SOAPUI free tool is not working

Tags: soapui, ready-api

We had used ReadyAPI to automate our SOAP/REST API Tests for few years. The tool has been installed in a build machine say **Machine A**. Now we have decided not to renew the license of the tool and we have exported the project(xml). The same was imported in freshly installed SOAPUI 5.5.0 free tool in **Machine B** and it is working fine.
But when I removed the ReadyAPI in the **Machine A** and installed SOAPUI free tool, I'm not able to import my project. Importing project in workspace is grayed out and when right-clicking It is showing only reload and Remove option. Reloading is not helping too. Refer the attached screenshot.

Please suggest workaround to make soapui free tool import my existing project in the same machine where ReadyAPI was installed earlier.

P.S I have done a clean uninstall by the steps given by Smartbear (deleted default-soapui-workspace.xml, soapui-settings.xml and .soapui folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible, from the SmartBear [forums](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Import-readyAPI-project-in-free-SOAPUI/td-p/182345). It is in the vendor's interest to let you continue paying.

Comment: Thanks. But the project exported from ReadyAPI is working fine in another machine where I installed SOAPUI open tool freshly. This exported project is not working only in the same machine's SOAPUI opensource tool where I just uninstalled ReadyAPI and installed this SOAPUI open source tool

Comment: Then there may be a config setting somewhere in the windows user directory. The project is just XML, you can read through it and compare. Check user/AppData and so on for settings left behind too.